# Nginx Failed to start

Tags: python, nginx, flask

this is the first server setup. I dumped up to 30 virtual machines until this stage. I think this is the last step but I can't start nginx any kind !!

```
(venv) ubuntu@excelrepair:/excelrepair$ sudo service nginx reload
nginx.service is not active, cannot reload.
(venv) ubuntu@excelrepair:/excelrepair$ sudo service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
(venv) ubuntu@excelrepair:/excelrepair$
```

I did not get any results from these and I tried the error reports

sudo nginx -t

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

journalctl -xe

```
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair rsyslogd[9013]: action 'action-8-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), >
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair nginx[17402]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/c>
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair nginx[17402]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit nginx.service has exited.
-- 
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit nginx.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit nginx.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit nginx.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 2708 and the job result is failed.
Jun 28 14:59:57 excelrepair sudo[17393]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 28 15:00:01 excelrepair CRON[17416]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 28 15:00:01 excelrepair CRON[17417]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.da>
Jun 28 15:00:01 excelrepair CRON[17416]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

And last;

nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020/06/28 15:01:49 [warn] 17480#17480: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2020/06/28 15:01:49 [emerg] 17480#17480: cannot load certificate "/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

i cant find what is wrong..! Any help pls..
Thanks from now

Comment: You say you can't find what is wrong but the answer is clearly stated in the error message: `nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)`. You have to have the certificate file existing. If you don't then generate it.

Comment: I noticed with your warning that I saved the cert file to an incorrect directory. It got better when it was put in the right directory. Thank you for that.
Now I'm trying to get rid of the "502 Bad Gataway" error :)

Comment: Investigate update error logs.

Answer (score 0):

here are two files that must be configured on the Nginx server, the certificate .crt and the certificate key .key, you simply have to have these 2 files on your Nginx server.

And using a server block which are Nginx configuration files, located in the path /etc/nginx/sites-available, in your server block you must write the 2 lines that refer to your certificate and key.

Inside the server block you must have:

```
ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/excelrepair/keys/nameofyourkey.key;
ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pem;
```

Where in each line you specify the path of the files.

But you should check that the certificate file `.cert` and the key file `.key` are in the path that your configuration file says it is in.

Comment: .I think I got this problem by moving the cert folder to the right directory. However, I currently cannot get rid of the "502 Bad Gateway" warning.
Could it be related to the two lines you described?
I found the file 'default' in the sites-aviable folder and added these two lines to the server block.
I have this dirctory and file:
 /home/ubuntu/excelrepair/certs/cert.pe;
but i don't have the key folder in this directory:
/home/ubuntu/excelrepair/keys/nameofyourkey.key;
Should I enter the value given by the code "cat ~ / .ssh / id_rsa.pub" instead of nameofyourkey?
thanks for kind helps

Comment: "nameofyourkey" does not refer to the public key of ssh, therefore it is not "cat ~ / .ssh / id_rsa.pub", with that line I mean the key of the certificate, the same way you got the .cert you must also have the .key, the key of your certificate.

Comment: Nor should it be included in a general nginx configuration file, but rather in a domain-specific one, since the SSL certificate targets to a domain.